# В чем смысл второй матрицы в алгоритме Флойда

Tags: c++

хотел уточнить один момент по алгоритму флойда : на сайтах пишут что после итерации цикла с k нужно копировать значения из получившейся матрицы в новую, которая также будет проверять все вершины на наличие кратчайших путей через вершину k+1 . Можно вообще реализовать это с двумя матрицами , и если да , то как ? Надеюсь на вашу помощь

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void Print(int** A, int size)
{
    //вывод номеров узлов
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << i + 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    //вывод значений графа
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << A[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void Floyd_Algorithm(int** A, int** C, int size)
{
    
    
    
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        int** tmp = C;
        C = A;
        A = tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = min(A[i][j], A[i][k] + A[k][j]);
                
            }
        }
    }

    
}


int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter the size of graph" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    system("cls");
    
    //основной граф
    int** A = new int* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new int[size];
    }
    
    //матрица для изменений
    int** C = new int* [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        C[i] = new int[size];
    }
    
    //инициализация путей в узлах
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) A[i][j] = 0;
            else if (1 + rand() % 10 > 2)
            {
                A[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 9;
            }
            else
            {
                A[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    Print(A, size);
    Floyd_Algorithm(A, C, size);
    Print(A, size);
    Print(C, size);
    
    
    
    
    //удаление 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] A[i];
    }
    delete[] A;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] C[i];
    }
    delete[] C;
}
```

Comment: Просто есть матрица исходная A, и вычисляемая B.  Вычислили B. В плохом варианте просто копируем B в A. В хорошем :) - используем, например, указатели - и обмениваем их. И опять у нас в A - исходная, в B - то, что будем вычислять на новом шаге.

Comment: А как эти указатели можно обменять ? например есть два массива A (исходная) B(вычисляемая), можете показать на примере пожалуйста?

Comment: В каком виде у вас массивы? Как объявлены?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас матрица создается примерно как

```
int ** A = new int*[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) A[i] = new int[M];
```

и такая же `B` - все особенно просто:

```
// Вычисление B из A
int ** tmp = A;
A = B;
B = tmp;
```

и - на новый круг :)

Comment: если я правильно понимаю , то мне нужно вставить замену после первой фигурной скобки цикла k в Floyd_Algorithm ?

Comment: прикрепил код алгоритма

Answer (score 1):

Вторая матрица вовсе не обязательна, алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла устроен так, что все изменения можно делать в исходной матрице.

[e-maxx:](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/floyd_warshall_algorithm)

> Последнее замечание, которое следует сделать, — то, что можно не
> создавать отдельную матрицу d[][] для временной матрицы кратчайших
> путей на k-ой фазе: все изменения можно делать сразу в матрице d[][].
> В самом деле, если мы улучшили (уменьшили) какое-то значение в матрице
> расстояний, мы не могли ухудшить тем самым длину кратчайшего пути для
> каких-то других пар вершин, обработанных позднее.